# How to transfer values from one jsp to different jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a file demo1.jsp and using form tag I jumped to demo2.jsp where by using the `getParameter()` method I accessed the values of demo1.jsp. Now I want the values of demo1.jsp in demo3.jsp. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you moving from demo1.jsp to demo2.jsp and then to demo3.jsp

Answer (score 0):

At `demo1.jsp` you can set a variable to a request -

```
request.setAttribute( "varName", varVal );
```

After that at `demo2.jsp` you can get the variable put in the session like this -

```
request.getAttribute( "varName" );
```

Comment: why do you want to put it in session, we can simply use request. unnecessary overloading of session is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways by using which you can do that:

either you can add in **session** object attributes

or you can add in **request** object attributes

or you can pass the parameter in URL

or you can use **hidden** parameter also.

if you use below two options you can get field in `request.getParameter("field");`